# How to pass variables defined in one jsp to another and then again after processing in another jsp include that jsp in first jap page

Tags: java, jsp

I need to pass values from one jsp to another jsp and then the values are processed in that another jsp and then that jsp will be included in first jsp.

The jsp variables which I need to pass are from Comp_Mps_hs.jsp to Comp_Mps_hs_diff.jsp are

```
<jsp:useBean id="ref" class="comp_Mps.Comp_Mps_hs"/>

<br>

  <%
//Comaprision obj = new Comaprision();
   String s_date= request.getParameter("startdate");
   pageContext.setAttribute("s_date", s_date);
   String e_date= request.getParameter("enddate");
   pageContext.setAttribute("e_date", e_date);
   ref.refarray_vac1(s_date,e_date);
   ref.ClosestToMultiplesOfTen_User(s_date,e_date);

%>


<%
//Comaprision reference = new Comaprision();
   String ref_name= request.getParameter("ref_logtime");
   pageContext.setAttribute("ref_name", ref_name);
   ref.FindClosestToMultiplesOfTen(ref_name);
   ref.refernece(ref_name);

%>

<br><br><br>

 <table width = "170%" border = "1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
 <th>Date_Time</th>
     <th>beam_current</th>
     <th>beam_energy</th>
     <%
     for(int i=51; i<99;i++){
     %>
       <th>p<%=i%>_readback</th>
        <th>p<%=i%>_setvalue</th>
        <th>p<%=i%>_vmeset</th>
        <th>p<%=i%>_dacbyadc</th>
     <%
     }
     %>
     <!--  


   </tr>


<c:set var="count" value="0" scope="session" />

<c:forEach var="row" items="${ref.refarray_vac1(param.startdate,param.enddate)}">
<c:forEach var="r" items="${ref.refernece(param.ref_logtime)}" begin="${count}" end="${count}"> 

<tr bgcolor="darkgray ">
<td><c:out value="${r.logtime}"></c:out></td>
<td>
<c:out value="${r.beam_current}"></c:out> </td>
<td>
<c:out value="${(r.beam_energy)}"/> 
</td>
<td>
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p51_readback)}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2"  var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
<c:out value="${(r.p51_readback)}"/> 
</td>
<td>
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p51_setvalue)}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2"  var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
<c:out value="${(mm)}"/> 
</td>
</tr>

<!-- For user_selection color name-- darkkhaki -->

<tr bgcolor="cornsilk">

<td><c:out value="${row.logtime}"></c:out></td>

<td>
<c:out value="${row.beam_current}"></c:out> </td>

<td>
<c:out value="${(row.beam_energy)}"/> 
</td>

<td>
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(row.p51_readback)}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2"  var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
<c:out value="${(row.p51_readback)}"/> 
</td>
<td>
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(row.p51_setvalue)}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2"  var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
<c:out value="${(mm)}"/> 
</td>
</tr>


<tr>

<td>Deviation</td>

<jsp:include page="Mps_Hs_diff.jsp"></jsp:include>**Here I need to include another jsp  as the cod ewas becoming large**


<c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" scope="session" />
</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>


 </table>

</body>
```

The another page where I need the values of r and row which are declared in this page is

```
<body>
<jsp:useBean id="ref" class="comp_Mps.Comp_Mps_hs"/>

<br>

  <%
//Comaprision obj = new Comaprision();
   String s_date= request.getParameter("startdate");
   pageContext.setAttribute("s_date", s_date);
   String e_date= request.getParameter("enddate");
   pageContext.setAttribute("e_date", e_date);
   ref.refarray_vac1(s_date,e_date);
   ref.ClosestToMultiplesOfTen_User(s_date,e_date);

%>


<%
//Comaprision reference = new Comaprision();
   String ref_name= request.getParameter("ref_logtime");
   pageContext.setAttribute("ref_name", ref_name);
   ref.FindClosestToMultiplesOfTen(ref_name);
   ref.refernece(ref_name);

%>

<br><br><br>



 <table width = "170%" border = "1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <c:set var="row" value="${ref.refarray_vac1(param.startdate,param.enddate)}"></c:set>
 <c:set var="r" value="${ref.refernece(param.ref_logtime)}"></c:set>
 <tr>


<td scope="row" style="${r.beam_current-row.beam_current eq 0 ? 'background-color: lime':'background-color: pink'}">
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.beam_current-row.beam_current)}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2"  var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
<c:out value="${mm}" ></c:out></td>


<td scope="row" style="${r.beam_energy-row.beam_energy eq 0 ? 'background-color: lime':'background-color: pink'}">
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.beam_energy-row.beam_energy)}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2"  var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
<c:out value="${mm}" ></c:out></td>

<td style="${r.p51_readback-row.p51_readback eq 0 ? 'background-color: lime':'background-color: pink'}">
<fmt:formatNumber value="${((r.p51_readback-row.p51_readback))}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.##" var="nn"></fmt:formatNumber>
<c:out value="${nn}"></c:out>
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p51_readback-row.p51_readback)/r.p51_readback}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" type="percent" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
<c:out value="(${mm})" ></c:out></td>
```

But the first page is never called by the user, an another page is called on whose button click the first jsp is called.So the values in the page which I included are never processed as it is never called.

Comment: Session objetcs are normally used to persist data across pages...

Comment: @AlainBUFERNE,I will use page scope.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the session scope in order to have your variable available in any JSP or servlet during the current session.

You can store your variables in the session scope:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String variableToPass = "hello";
session.setAttribute("variableToPass", variableToPass);
```

And, you can access them like this:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String variablePassed = session.getAttribute("variableToPass");
```

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: ,can I use the  this variableToPass in another JSP page .Actually I have to include a JSP page into another jsp page and the page which is to be included should have values from the first page i.e the page into whi ch it is to be included.